# Send a text message to without redirecting to default messaging app (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, sms, messaging

I'm fairly new to Android app development and I'm trying to make the app so you type in the text field the recipients phone number in one text field and the message in another, then press a button for it to send Without going to the default messaging app. I've done some research but not a lot of their solutions worked. If you come up with a solution, could you add a brief reason as to why it works. Also I'm not too sure if I correctly added the Send_SMS and Receive_SMS permissions correctly:

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText no,msg;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    no = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
    msg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonsms);



    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String noString = no.getText().toString();
            String msgMsg = msg.getText().toString();
            sendSms(noString, msgMsg);
        }
    });
}

private void sendSms(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.skiddswarmik.messageproto">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what your problems are with your existing code.

Comment: The problem is it sends be to the Messages app rather than just sending it straight from the app itself

Comment: I do not see how that is possible in this code. `sendTextMessage()` should send the text message directly. If you have not done so already, try testing this on the Android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

It should send the message directly . Plz remove the pending intent line .If there is a problem ,provide the phone number   in proper format with country code prefixed .

You can see this answer for help    :
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38940244/5879376

Comment: So should it be like 1(234)467-8901 or should it should it be 12345678901 for the phone number. I've set the input format as the second one. Also, how would i implement the code in the link to this code?

Comment: As given in the link , use the required code to select proper contact to which sms is to be sent .